# how to check if type 'T' has 'T(std::initializer_list<U>)' constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, sfinae

I have a function `func <T> (...)` which must be separated into two branches;

- 1st branch: case when type `T` have `T(std::initializer_list<U>)` constructor.
- 2nd branch: case when type `T` does not have `T(std::initializer_list<U>)` constructor.

My current implementation is as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
using has_init_list_ctor = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<
    T,
    std::initializer_list<U>
>>;

// version for T with initialization list ctor
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T, /* idk how to auto-deduce type U */>
    >
>
void func() {
    //... 
}

// version for T without initialization list ctor
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T, /* idk how to auto-deduce type U */>
    >
>
void func() {
    //... 
}
```

But it have a flaw. I have no idea how to auto-deduce type `U` from `T`.

the ideal solution would be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct deduce_U_from_T
{
    // implementation.

    usign type = /* ??? */;
};

template<typename T>
using has_init_list_ctor = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<
    T,
    std::initializer_list<
        typename deduce_U_from_T<T>::type
    >
>>;
```

but i have no idea how to implement `deduce_U_from_T`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
or is there any workaround?

---

**Update:**

Function `func <T> (...)` is an imitation of `std::alocator_traits::construct()`. 
I am trying to implement my own "allocator" for the use of `std::vector` and smart pointers. Under normal circumstances, I would use the default `std::alocator_traits`, but this time, I need to request memory from the "special" pool (it is something implemented by me, it can be called "virtual heap", it is accessed via methods like `T * get_memory <T> (...)`, the pool performs additional operations during mem allocation, and offers different "modes" of allocation - I am sorry for being very generic but currently it is WIP, and it constantly changes)

simplistic implementation of `func <T> (...)` (`allocator_traits::construct()`)

```cpp
template<typename T>
class allocator_traits
{
//...

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T>,
        void
    > construct(T * ptr, Args && ... args)
    {
        new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // normal brackets // construct with placment-new
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    static
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_detected_v<has_init_list_ctor, T>,
        void
    > construct(T * ptr, Args && ... args)
    {
        new(ptr) T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }; // curly brackets // construct with placment-new
    }

//...
};
```

The difference lies in the ability to construct type `T` with curly brackets (when type `T` doesn't have `T(std::initializer_list<U>)` constructor.

Comment: XY problem? What is `func()` actually going to do, and why do you care if `T` has an `initializer_list<U>` constructor for some arbitrary `U` (as opposed to some specific `U`)?

Comment: This is only possible if `U` is a discrete type. If it is a template type that must be deduced, I'm afraid it is un-possible. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: If nothing else, `T` may have multiple constructors taking `std::initializer_list<U>` for different `U`. For this reason alone, the goal of "auto-deduce type `U` from `T`" is likely hopeless. Why do you feel you need this? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: please give me a "second" to edit the question and include "missing" info on what does the `func <T> (...)` do.

Comment: sorry for the wait, I've updated the question.

Comment: Isn't `U` the `std::common_type_t<Args...>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 No. `U` may not even have anything to do with `Args...`. Consider `vector<char>{1, 2, 3}` or `vector<string>{"a", "bc", "def"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to solve this problem?

Yes. Don't solve it. You shouldn't be trying to guess what kind of initialization the user wants. Just do this:

```
new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

If the user wants to use an `initializer_list` constructor, they can pass in an instance of an `initializer_list` and that'll work just fine.

The more interesting case is aggregates, which is why they will be initializable with parentheses in C++20 (see [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html)).  But that can be worked around by passing in an argument which has an appropriate conversion operator. That is, if I want to construct a:

```
struct X { int i; };
```

and make that work with parentheses, I can pass in an argument of type:

```
struct X_factory { int i; operator X() const { return X{i}; } };
```

and with guaranteed copy elision, we get the right effect anyway.

---

In any case, `initializer_list` actually isn't strictly related to the question. What you probably would have wanted (and I wouldn't suggest doing this) is:

```
if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>) {
    new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
} else {
    new (ptr) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

Or possibly in the reverse order writing a trait for direct-list-initializable.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the factory is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1):

@Barry is right, this is a bad idea.

Here is how to do it:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct any_il{
    template<class U>
    operator std::initializer_list<U>()const{ return {}; }
};

struct foo {
    foo(std::initializer_list<int>){}
    foo(foo&&)=default;
};

template<class T, class=void>
struct can_from_il:std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct can_from_il<T, decltype(void( T(any_il{}) ) )>:std::true_type{};

int main(){
    std::cout << can_from_il<foo>{}() << can_from_il<int>{}() <<"\n";
}
```

It has many flaws.